# CodeIgniter Undefined property

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a small problem, i am trying to display messages for a user which should take a parameter of the user i choose.

But i am not sure whats going wrong here

Controller

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('ViewMessages');
    }
    public function view($name)
    {
        $this->load->model("Messages_Model");
        $data ['results']  = $this->Messages_model->getMessagesByPoster($name);
        $this->load->view("ViewMessages", $data);
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php
class Messages_model extends CI_Model{
    function getMessagesByPoster($name)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_username='$name'");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>View Messages</h1>
<h2></h2>
<div id="Main">
    <?php
    foreach($results as $row){
        echo $row ->id;
        echo $row ->user_username;
        echo $row ->text;
        echo $row ->posted_at;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Error
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: User::$Messages_model

Filename: controllers/User.php

Line Number: 13

Comment: Where do you see the undefined property ? In the foreach in your view ? Could you paste the exact error ?

Comment: sorry, i edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this one

Controller: (User.php)

```
  <?php
    class User extends CI_Controller {
        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('ViewMessages');
        }
        public function view($name)
        {
            $this->load->model("Messages_model");  //Case sensitive you have written Messages_Model
            $data ['results']  = $this->Messages_model->getMessagesByPoster($name);
            $this->load->view("ViewMessages", $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your model page was `Messages_model.php` but you are loading `Messages_Model.php` . it just a  Case sensitive issue